# getting an error param tags must be an array while tagging facebook users

Tags: facebook

I am creating the facebook app(php sdk) that uploads photo and tags users.But i am getting a strange below error

```
   Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) param tags must be an array.
```

I used the following code

```
$argstag = array('to' => $user);  
$argstag['x'] = 40;  
$argstag['y'] = 40; 
$data = json_encode($argstag); 
$attachment = array( 

            'message' => $mes,
'tags' => $data
          );
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$attachment['image'] ='@'.realpath($filename);
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$aid.'/photos', 'POST', $attachment);
```

please help me with this issue.

Comment: I’m not sure if you actually have to json-encode that parameter yourself – normally the SDK should take care of that itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$argstag = array('to' => $user);
```

to

```
$argstag = array('tag_uid' => $user);
```

EDIT:

If that doesn't work try changing

```
$argstag = array('to' => $user);  
$argstag['x'] = 40;  
$argstag['y'] = 40; 
$data = json_encode($argstag);
```

to

```
 $armstag = array();
 $armstag['tag_uid'] = $user;
 $armstag['x'] = 40;
 $armstag['y'] = 40;
  $data = json_encode($argstag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing out the $argstag? It will show you the array you are encoding with json and it will look like this probably [[x:something],[y:something]] etc. use str_replace to replace those unwanted elements. Here is what i'm using when inviting users:

```
$torep=array("[","]",'"');//replace some chars. generetaded by json
$users=str_replace($torep,"", $encode);
```

The output is: UID, UID, UID, UID which is working instead of [[UID],[UID],[UID]] which gives me the same error.

Hope it helps ;)